# Where are Python libraries installed on Docker container from AWS Lambda Python image?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a lambda function using a Docker image, but I want to modify some of the code in the Python packages I'm installing. I can't find where the packages are installed for me to modify the source code.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/project

COPY lambda_handler.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "lambda_handler.lambda_handler" ]
```

**Question:** Where are the packages from the `requirements.txt` file installed? I tried going into the container but it doesn't give me the bash terminal because the container is made from a Lambda image, which requires the entry point to be the lambda handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the entrypoint of the image and then print the paths that python searches for packages.

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint python \
  public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 -c 'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))'

/var/lang/lib/python38.zip
/var/lang/lib/python3.8
/var/lang/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Given what we find above, you can enter a bash shell in your built image and look at the contents of

```
/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

with the following:

```sh
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
ls /var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!